# Get the RootView controller from the dataViewController in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios

I have a **rootViewController**, which uses **UIPageViewController** to display some **dataViewControllers**, I'm wondering how can I get my ***rootViewController*** in ***dataViewController***, sometimes I just need to refresh the UI of rootViewController, and I don't want to use Notification.

I use this in my dataViewController, however it only get me to the UIPageViewController.

```
- (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    for (UIView* next = [self.view superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
        UIResponder *nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        NSLog(@"%@",[nextResponder class]);
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIPageViewController class]]) {
            return (UIViewController *)nextResponder;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIPageViewController` can have weak reference to parent view controller (rootViewController) and pass that reference to other controllers which are nested in pageController.

You have to notice that all reference to parent controller(rootViewController) should be weak, in that way you will avoid strong reference cycles.